# Drag objects in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode4.5

I'm trying to drag an object from the object library, and while with the magic mouse I have no problem, using the Trackpad doesn't result in placing the object in it's place.

I have 3 finger drag option selected in the Trackpad settings.

What is the right way to drag (and Control-drag) objects in Interface Builder?

Thanks!